# Set OpenFolderDialog to a special folder

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

I know it is possible to set the current folder of the OpenFolderDialog to a special folder, like "Program Files" or Desktop?

But where do I find this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the System.Environment class, e.g:

```
string programFiles = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
     System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

Update:

I'm not sure if this is part of the question, but to open the folder selection dialog, you then use this code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

//...

FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.SelectedPath = programFiles;
dialog.ShowDialog();

string selectedPath = dialog.SelectedPath;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the folder to `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)`? This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set the initial folder of the `OpenFolderDialog` to the result of `System.Environment.GetFolderPath()`.